# How to serialize an OAuth1Session?

Tags: python, oauth

I currently have a monolithic Python script which performs an OAuth authentication, returning an `OAuth1Session`, and then proceeds to perform some business logic using that `OAuth1Session` to gain authorization to a third-party service.

I need to split this up into two separate scripts, one which performs the OAuth authentication and will run on one machine, and the other which will run on a remote machine to perform the business logic authorized against the third-party service.

How can I serialize the `OAuth1Session` object so that the authenticated tokens can be handed off seamlessly from the *authentication script* on machine `A` to the *processing script* on machine `B`?

I tried the obvious:

> `print(json.dumps(session))`

But I got this error:

> `TypeError: Object of type OAuth1Session is not JSON serializable`

Is there a canonical solution for this simple requirement?

***UPDATE***

Here's the entire source code. Please note this is not my code, I downloaded it from the author and now I'm trying to modify it to work a bit differently.

```
"""This Python script provides examples on using the E*TRADE API endpoints"""
from __future__ import print_function
import webbrowser
import json
import logging
import configparser
import sys
import requests
from rauth import OAuth1Service

def oauth():
    """Allows user authorization for the sample application with OAuth 1"""
    etrade = OAuth1Service(
        name="etrade",
        consumer_key=config["DEFAULT"]["CONSUMER_KEY"],
        consumer_secret=config["DEFAULT"]["CONSUMER_SECRET"],
        request_token_url="https://api.etrade.com/oauth/request_token",
        access_token_url="https://api.etrade.com/oauth/access_token",
        authorize_url="https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key={}&token={}",
        base_url="https://api.etrade.com")

    base_url = config["DEFAULT"]["PROD_BASE_URL"]

    # Step 1: Get OAuth 1 request token and secret
    request_token, request_token_secret = etrade.get_request_token(
        params={"oauth_callback": "oob", "format": "json"})

    # Step 2: Go through the authentication flow. Login to E*TRADE.
    # After you login, the page will provide a text code to enter.
    authorize_url = etrade.authorize_url.format(etrade.consumer_key, request_token)
    webbrowser.open(authorize_url)
    text_code = input("Please accept agreement and enter text code from browser: ")

    # Step 3: Exchange the authorized request token for an authenticated OAuth 1 session
    session = etrade.get_auth_session(request_token,
                                  request_token_secret,
                                  params={"oauth_verifier": text_code})

    return(session, base_url)


# loading configuration file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(sys.argv[1])
(session, base_url) = oauth()

print(base_url)
print(json.dumps(session))

#original code
#market = Market(session, base_url)
#quotes = market.quotes(sys.argv[2])
```

Please note the **last two commented-out lines**. That is the original code: Immediate after the oauth is performed, the code invokes some business functionality. I want to break this up into two separate scripts running as isolated processes: Script 1 performs the oauth and persists the session, Script 2 reads the session from a file and performs the business functionality.

Unfortunately it fails at the last line, `print(json.dumps(session))`.

***"XY Problem" Alert***

My goal is to split up the script into two so that the business logic can run in a separate machine from the authentication code. I believe that the way to do this is to serialize the `session` object and then parse it back in the second script. Printing out the session using `json.dumps()` is an **intermediate step, 'Y'**, in my journey to solving **problem 'X'**. If you can think of a better way to achieve the goal, that could be a valid answer.

Comment: I can't quite understand your question. Is it related to https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/oauth1.html ?

Comment: I have `from rauth import OAuth1Service`. I'll attach the entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments available in the source code here: https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/a6d887d7737cf21ec896a8104f25c2754c694011/rauth/session.py

You only need to serialize some attributes of your object to reinstantiate it:

```
    Line 103
    def __init__(self,
                     consumer_key,
                     consumer_secret,
                     access_token=None,
                     access_token_secret=None,
                     signature=None,
                     service=None):
     ...
```

Thus I would suggest serializing the following dict on the first machine:

```
info_to_serialize = {
    'consumer_key': session.consumer_key,
    'consumer_secret': session.consumer_secret,
    'access_token': session.access_token,
    'access_token_secret': session.access_token_secret
}
serialized_data = json.dumps(info_to_serialize)
```

And on the second machine reinstantiate your session like that:

```
from rauth.session import OAuth1Session

info_deserialized = json.loads(serialized_data)
session = OAuth1Session(**info_deserialized)
```

Hope this helped

Comment: I edited your answer. The `signature` and `service` parameters were causing errors but this works when I remove them! Thank you for showing the way.